# Windows 2003 Session/Connections

Tags: windows-server-2003

Right now I have two servers.  Server A runs a vbscript that copies files from Server B via UNC paths.  Both servers have different login information.  The password on Server B was just changed and now Server A can't connect.
Before I would have to use Run to open the UNC path and enter the login info, but now after the password was changed I get this error:

\\SERVER-B\Backup is not accessible.
Multiple connections to a server or shared resource by the same user, using more that one user name, are not allower.  Disconnect all previous connections to the server of shared resource and try again.

I have gone into control panel and removed everything from Stored User Names and Password, and that didn't work.  There are no other users logged in either.  How do I disconnect the connection without rebooting the Servers?

Both Servers are running windows 2003 standard w/SP2.
And I do not have the ability to change the password back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open a command window
2. Type `net use` and note all of the shares that you see with the ServerB in the path
3. type `net use /d` followed by the share name for anything that says ServerB in it.  These connections are what are holding on to your old authentication info.

After all of those have been disconnected you should be able to connect to shares on ServerB with the new password.